# Can't send mail on 000WebHost with PHP

Tags: email, php

I have made a small php project on [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com). The system I have set up sends mail to the user if he/she forgets password to reset it. But the problem is that it can't send mail at all.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$tomail=$_POST["usermail"];
$subject="Password Reset";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '.$tomail."\r\n";
$link="https://dhankosh-in.000webhostapp.com/reset_password.php";
$message="<html><head></head><body><p>Click on the link below to reset your password</p><br><br><a href='".$link."'>Click here to reset your password</a></body></html>";
if(mail($tomail,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    $myobj=array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Check your mail to reset password!!');
    echo json_encode($myobj);
}
else{
    $myobj=array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Invalid e-mail!!');
    echo json_encode($myobj);
}
```

It sends the response as “Check your mail to reset password!!” but I don't receive any mail.

Comment: Can you check mail server log files?

Comment: Perhaps 000webhost don't provide one!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code and it worked. (I edited the first line to be a fixed email address).

Turn on sendmail in the control panel (if it's off)

Website settings > General > Sendmail

Be aware that the free account is limited to 50 emails per day.

Comment: When I tried it for first time, it actually sent mail for once. But now it is not working!!

Comment: sometimes free services are worth less than what you paid, regrettably that may include this answer also.

Comment: Yes, it sends mail after 2-3 hours!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very late...

Check with your webhost, 000webhost, as they might have disabled PHPMail() functionality, as it is major vector for spam/malware.  Many web hosting providers have disabled PHPMail() for this very reason.